# How to partition a plane

Tags: coordinates, polygon, plane

Let's say I have a fixed number (X) of points, e.g. coordinates within a given plane (I think you can call it a 2-D point cloud).

These points should be partitioned into Y polygons where Y < X. The polygons should not overlap. It would be wonderful if the polygons were konvex (like a Voronoi diagram).

Imagine it like locations forming countries. For example, I have 12 points and want to create 3 polygons with 4 points each.

I thought about creating a grid which covers the points. Then iterate across the points, assigning them to the closest grid cells.

Maybe I miss the obvious? I am sure there are better solutions.

Thanks,
Daniel

I just found [an optimization (kmeans++)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means%2B%2B) .Maybe this will yield better results..

Comment: With a grid, you might get empty cells, or all points in one cell.  With a radial array you can overcome this with a solution that is quick and easy to implement.

Answer (score 1):

You mention the Voronoi diagram, have you looked at the related [tesselation algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram)? If so, could you emphasize why they don't work for you?

Comment: Voronoi diagrams have a single point per polygon, here however any number of points should make up the polygon. What I forgot to mention: I have also tried Lloyd's Algorithm (k-means) but the result depends too much on the initial selection.. the convergence is generally not too good.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to better define what criteria you wish to use to create your polygonal partitions.  For example, if it is proximity, you could do the following;

- Construct a voronoi diagram.
- Where any two adjacent polygons have a close neighbour, merge them into a single polygon
- Repeat until you have the desired number of polygons

If it was equal number of points per polygon, you could do something similar based on merging adjacent polygons with until a desired point count is met.

**Edit:** If convexity was the most important issue, you could simply take a point in the middle of you cloud and project radials to the edge to divide the cloud into a radial array of triangles.

Answer (score 0):

Might be useful [2D Polygon Partitioning](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/3.4/doc_html/cgal_manual/Partition_2/Chapter_main.html)